# Primary Rational Canonical form Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

As I just posted before on [Lost on rational and Jordan forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593753/lost-on-rational-and-jordan-forms), I'm practising with jordan forms, rational canonical forms...

Well, now I'm stuck in a problem because I don't know where I'm wrong.

I have this matrix:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 4 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
 1 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 &  3\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and I have to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}MP=C$ where $C$ represents the primary rational canonical form of M.

I've computed the characteristic polynomial ($(x-3)^4$) and the minimal polynomial ($(x-3)^3$). Therefore, the invariants factors and the elementary divisors are the same  ($(x-3)^3$ and $(x-3)$) and the primary rational canonical form is the same as the rational canonical form, which is:

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 27\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -27\\
 0 & 0 & 1 &  9\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

since $(x-3)^3=x^3-9x^2+27x-27$.

Now, in order to get $P$, I just need a basis which is going to be formed by $\{u,v,Mv,M^2v\}$ where $u$ is a vector such that $(3I-M)u=0$ and $v$ is a vector such that $(3I-M)u\neq0$, $(3I-M)^2u\neq0$ and linearly independent from $u$.

So, in this conditions, I chose $u=(0,1,1,0)$ and $v=(1,1,0,1)$. Then, my basis is $\{(0,1,1,0),(1,1,0,1),(2,4,2,3),(3,14,11,9)\}$. Finally:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
 1 & 1 & 4 & 14\\
 1 & 0 & 2 & 11\\
 0 & 1 & 3 &  9\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

However, $P^{-1}MP\neq C$, as you can check 
[here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28inverse+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C4%2C14%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C2%2C11%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C3%2C9%7D%7D%29*+%7B%7B4%2C-1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C3%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C3%7D%7D*%7B%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C4%2C14%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C2%2C11%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C3%2C9%7D%7D).

---

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Variable The matrix $M$ was written wrong. Now it is perfect. The eigenvalues are apparently the same, so I didn't notice.  Using the basis you wrote above, and the "previous" $M$, the calculus gave me the Jordan form, not the canonical form. Now it comes the wierd stuff: Using chaining for the correct $M$, the basis is this: $v_{1,2,3,4} = ((0, 1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 0, 0),(1, -1, 0, 0),(0, 1, 1, 0))$ Notice that looks almost the same as yours. However, checking, it does not give me the jordan form.  So, everything seems wrong. I'm confused.