# Complex eigenvalues Jordan real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

As I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593753/lost-on-rational-and-jordan-forms) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594093/primary-rational-canonical-form-matrix) I'm studying Jordan forms and similar concepts.

I've got a problem with complex eigenvalues in jordan real matrices. I know (at least I think so) how to compute the Jordan blocks for real eigenvalues. However, I don't know how to do it with complex ones. Let's illustrate this with an example:

Let $M$ be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 4\\
 0 & 0& -4 & -6 &-4\\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 4\\
 0 & 2 & 0 & -4 & -4\\
 -2 & -4 & -2 &  2 & 2\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The charasteristic polynomial is $(x-2)(x^2+4)^2$. I know the Jordan real form is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0& -2 & 0 &0\\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
 0 & 0& 0 &  2 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

but I don't understand why. The block corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ is clear, but I'm completely lost about the complex eigenvalues and how to arrive to that matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} 0& -2\\2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? Does this matrix have eigenvalues as an endomorphism in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @Variable What do you mean by "CP"?  And no, everything is well copied.

Comment: @Roland I know they are $2i$ and $-2i$ and when we have a complex eigenvalue, the corresponding Jordan block is of some precise form. What I don't know is why it is twice and we ignore the conjugates.

Comment: @Variable I'm trying to find the **real** Jordan form. Even with complex eigenvalues, we can rewrite it as a **real** Matrix.

Comment: We are not ignoring conjugates. The block I quoted represents precisely (one instance of) $2i$  and its conjugate $-2i$. Note that the CP of the large matrix is $(\lambda - 2)(\lambda^2 +4)(\lambda^2 +4)$ and that we have _two_ identical factors each leading to $2i$ and its conjugate $-2i$. Each of the factors in brackets represents one block. The shape of the block, of course, depends on the eigenspace structure and the (possible) existence of Jordan chains. You can think of this matrix as a real representation of $diag(2i,-2i)$

Comment: @Roland  So, each block of a complex eigenvalue "represents" that eigenvalue and it's conjugate and the procedure to compute the size of the blocks and the amount of them is the same as in the real eigenvalues case (dimension of the kernel... until we reach the algebraic multiplicity). Then, instead of two blocks of size 1, could we have had one block of size 2? If yes, where would the "ones" be?

Comment: @V.Gonzalez you have the right idea.  In this context, the "1"s would be the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.  So, the Jordan real form of *another* matrix with this characteristic polynomial might be
$$
\pmatrix{
2&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-2&1&0\\
0&2&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&-2\\
0&0&0&2&0}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just another consult. In order to do the dimension of the kernel approach to discover the blocks for the complex eigenvalues, should I work with $(M+4I_{5})$ or with $(M-2iI_{5})$.

Comment: Work with second, noting that it is unnecessary to also work with $M+2iI$. If you want to do everything with real matrices, then you could accomplish the same thing by working with $M^2+4I$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Take a look at [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2%2C2%2C4%2C6%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-4%2C-6%2C-4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C4%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C0%2C-4%2C-4%7D%2C%7B-2%2C-4%2C-2%2C2%2C2%7D%7D%5E2). That is $M^2$. $M^2+4I$  has rank $1$, so $dim(ker))=4$. That makes no sense.

Comment: Why doesn't that make sense to you? Check what $J^2 +4I$ is, where $J$ is the Jordan real form.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom dim(ker) tells the number of blocks (of size at least 1). I follow [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jlindquist/115B/JCF.pdf). But I have already surpassed the algebraic multiplicity with step 1.

Comment: @V.Gonzalez I said that you could use $M^2+4I$, not that the rules would be exactly the same. Because we're considering $\pm 2i$ at the same time, every number here is double what you would get with $M-2iI$. So, $4/2=2$ means we have $2$ blocks of size at least $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, I see. Then I've just reached the algebraic multiplicity ($2$), so the process is finished. Thankyou very much!! If I could give you 10 points, I would!!